# Configuring multiple database in a NodeJS & MongoDB Backend --

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, axios, mern

How do I instantiate, configure and use multiple different MongoDB database names in a NodeJS ExpressJS backend project? I guess there is no concept of 'Tables' in MongoDB. I am using a database 'playerDB' and using it well for adding, fetching data etc. Now in my project I also want to have the concept of user login and registration [with roles] and hence the need of a new DB 'userDB'.

How do I do this? Is it at all allowable or permissible in Node Express Mongo domain? How should the project structure be? Do I write the mongoose connections and related stuff all in one server.js file or in different such files?

What is it? How should I do it?

Comment: Why don't you make these multiple collections in one database?

Comment: You can start here: https://docs.mongodb.com/ and here https://docs.mongodb.com/guides/

Comment: because I don't know if we can do that in MongoDB and how,
like we always do in MSSQL

Comment: can I just use the same 'playerDB' database and then inside it make some kind of separate tables [you said collection]     @jonrsharpe   can you forward a link?

Comment: Like in relational databases, you can have multiple tables inside one database, you can also have multiple collections in a mongo database. Table == Collection

Comment: @SuleymanSah   can you point me to an example or sample tutorial where they have done this so I can download and see?

Comment: Please read the MongoDB docs, they explain the basic ideas of using the database.

Comment: ok @jonrsharpe  let me go through that doc. Hopefully they will have a section to explain how to do this precisely.

Comment: hey @jonrsharpe  I figured out the first part. Just one more small step to go. Please check my comment under the below provided answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is how I basically achieved it. Like I mentioned, I had to alter some portions related to the JWT_SECRET.

My final server.js looks like this -->

```
        const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const PORT = 4000;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const playerRoutes = express.Router();
const userRoutes = express.Router();
const userController = require('./controllers/userController');
const user_routes = require('./apiroutes/route');
const app = express();

const JWT_SECRET = "$#GR24T4344$#$@#%WTEWTEAE%$6";


const users = "users";

require("dotenv").config({path: __dirname+ '../.env'});



let Player = require('./models/player.model');
let User = require('./models/user.model');

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(
    bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: false
    })
);

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/playerDB', function (err, db) {
    if (err)
        throw err;
    db.createCollection(users, function (err, resp) {
        if (err)
            throw err;
        console.log("Collection created!");

    });
}, { useNewUrlParser: true });


const connection = mongoose.connection;

connection.once('open', function () {
    console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully");
});

playerRoutes.route('/').get(function (req, res) {
    Player.find(function (err, players) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.json(players);
        }
    });
});


playerRoutes.route('/:id').get(function(req, res) {
    let id = req.params.id;
    Player.findById(id, function(err, player) {
        res.json(player);
    });
});

playerRoutes.route('/add').post(function (req, res) {
    let player = new Player(req.body);
    player.save()
        .then(player => {
            res.status(200).json({ 'player': 'player added successfully' });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(400).send('adding new player failed');
        });
});


var query = Player.find({ player_: "Hall of Fame" });


playerRoutes.route('/hallOfFame').get(function (req, res) {
    query.exec(function (err, players) {
        if (err) {
            return handleError(err);
        }
        else {
            res.json(players);
        }
    });
});


playerRoutes.route('/update/:id').post(function(req, res) {
    Player.findById(req.params.id, function(err, todo) {
        if (!player)
            res.status(404).send('player data is not found');
        else
            player.player_name = req.body.player_name;
            player.player_description = req.body.player_description;
            player.player_position = req.body.player_position;
            player.player_age=req.body.player_age;
            player.player_club=req.body.player_club;
            player.player_=req.body.player_;
            player.player_isactive = req.body.player_isactive;
            player.player_completed = req.body.player_completed;

            Player.save().then(player => {
                res.json('Player updated');
            })
            .catch(err => {
                res.status(400).send("Update not possible");
            });
    });
});


app.use('/playerDB', playerRoutes);


app.use(async (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.headers["x-access-token"]) {
        try {
            const accessToken = req.headers["x-access-token"];
            const { userId, exp } = await jwt.verify(accessToken, JWT_SECRET);
            // If token has expired
            if (exp < Date.now().valueOf() / 1000) {
                return res.status(401).json({
                    error: "JWT token has expired, please login to obtain a new one"
                });
            }
            res.locals.loggedInUser = await User.findById(userId);
            next();
        } catch (error) {
            next(error);
        }
    } else {
        next();
    }


});


app.use('/users', user_routes);


app.listen(PORT, function () {
    console.log("Server is running on Port: " + PORT);
});
```

I had my jwt secret value in a .env file. Had to bring it in the main file itself within a variable, as the ***require("dotenv")*** line is not working at all. Relevant packages are there in the node modules.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one database and multiple collections. Collections are like tables in Relational Database Management Systems. You can create a collection named "users", than you can use create, update, delete and fetch operations.

Comment: hi @jonrsharpe

I have created my Users collection inside the playerDB database. successfully. But problem is if I want to test my insert delete methods using postman right now. How do I send the request. To which collection, playerDB or Users? My backend is hosted at port 4000. So basically what I am asking is what should be my request format -->  localhost:4000/playerDB/Users   
OR
localhost:4000/Users          simply.     And thanks for helping to sort the first part out.

Comment: @PrabirChoudhury why would the REST API user care about the database name? They just care about the *resource*, which may or may not be the same as the collection name, probably `DELETE /users/:id`

Comment: @jonrsharpe  ok, let me try this part out a bit by myself. as of now, having some troubles; I tried with localhost:4000/users    [POST] and then some data to create a new user. But it failed. To double check I ran db.runCommand({listCollections:1}) just to make sure, that the playerDB.users collection exists and yes it does. give me a mo_ pls; going at it again.

Comment: I solved it. One small change did the necessary. I was making a mistake in the line app.use('/users', user_routes); Instead of the user_routes I was directly adding db name, ie like app.use('/users', 'users'). As such requests were incorrect. I am able to add new users now to users collection in the playerDB database. Through POSTMAN itself. It works now, for the moment; However I still had to make some adjustments to my code and project structure to make this work. Because I am using jwt mechanism while adding users and a whole lot of problems with bcrypt and jsonwebtoken packages !!  @jonrsh